# c# WebApi en capas con encriptación en base de datos

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, .net, linq, asp.net-web-api

Buenos días. Tengo un problema y no se como abordarlo.

Tengo generado un webapi por capas (controllers, servicios, acceso a datos, dto y dominios) y van a encriptar la base de datos a la que accede. Tambien van a crear unas funciones para encriptar y desencriptar la información.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿desde los dominios puedo hacer uso de dichas funciones de base de dato (de alguna forma) para que al aplicar el save se guarde la información encriptada y al hacer un select me llege a los dominios desencriptada? He pensado en los dominios porque sería el cambio mas simple, si alguien conoce otra forma, por favor, estoy abierto a sugerencias, pues no se por donde abordarlo.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento basico del sitio. Has de dar más informacion para poder responderte. Has intentado hacer uso de las funciones o algo? Respecto a las recomendaciones y sugerencias no es valido preguntar. Mira [ask] para más informacion. un saludo

Comment: no he probado a usar las funciones porque no se como hacerlo, por eso pregunto aqui, por si alguien ha usado alguna vez un webapi que se conecte a una base de datos encriptada

Comment: Si pero esa pregunta es muy amplia. Aqui las preguntas se basan en un trabajo previo y se expone lo intentado y por qué no ha funcionado.

Comment: Es dificil responder Alejandro. Falta información sobre como va a estar implementada la encriptación para poder hacernos una idea de como abordar el problema. En mi opinión es una pregunta demasiado amplia para el formato de [es.so]

Comment: Pues entonces creo que me he equivocado de sitio. No tengo ningun trabajo previo porque no se como hacerlo, lo que queria era saber de usuarios que hayan estado en la misma situacion que yo y como lo abordaron.

Comment: Cuando tengas 20 de reputacion podrás entrar en el [chat] donde puedes hacer preguntas amplias y a ver si algun conectado puede orientarte. un saludo